# How to use powershell to serialize lists in hashtables/arrays?

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable, hyper-v

I am serializing the output of the following script snippet, $VM contains a VM stored with Get-VM.

```
$VM.VMId | Get-VHD | Select @{N="Name";E={$VM.Name}},@{N="Disks";E={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,1)}}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Name                                                                                                                                             Disks
----                                                                                                                                             -----
ServerXYZ                                                                                                                                        136,7
ServerXYZ                                                                                                                                        465,7
```

But I want to somehow serialize this to instead give me:

```
Name                                                                                                                                             Disks
----                                                                                                                                             -----
ServerXYZ                                                                                                                                136,7 + 465,7
```

I have tried in vain to add -join " + " a bit here and there in the code to no avail.

I later on got to this point:

```
$VM.Name, (($VM.VMId | Get-VHD | foreach{ [math]::round($_.size/1GB,1)}) -join " + ")
```

This sort of comes close with actually making a list of the correct data that looks like "ServerXYZ, 136,7 + 465,7", but I would need to format this as an array or hashtable with key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
$vm.VMId | 
    Get-VHD |
        Select-Object @{N="Name";E={$VM.Name}},@{N="DiskSize";E={[math]::Round($_.Size/1gb,3)}} |
            Group-Object Name |
                ForEach-Object {
                    [PsCustomObject]@{
                        Name = $_.Name
                        Disks = $_.Group.DiskSize
                    }
                }
```

This gives output like this:

```
Name        Disks                       
----        -----                       
Server 1   {28.41, 0.223, 0.848, 0.816}
```

If you really want the '+' in-between, replace this line:

```
Disks = $_.Group.DiskSize
```

with:

```
Disks = ($_.Group.DiskSize -join ' + ')
```

This gives:

```
Name        Disks                        
----        -----                        
Server1     28.41 + 0.223 + 0.848 + 0.816
```

Comment: Oh yeah, this is real messy and convoluted, I love it!
Exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually I did stumble upon something strange, I can use this Disks value for an export to csv and in the powershell window I an see the value, but in the export the value turns into some sort of hash string like "c83d6b91-e645-48ed-9a62-fa00f40fcd17"

Comment: I edited my answer as I was overcomplicating the final part.  In any case, getting disk sizes with `Disks = $_.Group.DiskSize` means that the `Disks` property is an array, which displays on-screen ok, but doesn't export so well.  Using `Disks = ($_.Group.DiskSize -join ' + ')` makes it into a string, which should be fine - works for me anyway.

Comment: Yeah I got to the finish line myself by simply doing this instead:
$VHDs = $VHDs | Select-Object Name,@{N="Disks";E={$_.Disks -join " + "}}

Basically the same but maybe a bit uglier :P

Comment: Excellent.  Simpler than mine.

Comment: If you were curious, this is what I needed it for:
https://pastebin.com/yx2pVp9k

:)